# Where I'm making the mistake in rotating the image in following code?

Tags: php, image, function, reference, parameter-passing

I'm fixing the rotation of image. For it I've written following code but it's not working and I'm not getting the new image. Why so happening?

Following is the code :

```
$new_file_name = "demo_file.jpeg"
$new_image = image_fix_orientation($_FILES, $new_file_name);


function image_fix_orientation(&$image, $filename) {
    $image = imagerotate($image, array_values([0, 0, 0, 180, 0, 0, -90, 0, 90])[@exif_read_data($filename)['Orientation'] ?: 0], 0);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `image_fix_orientation`does not return anything. Yet you assign the result to `$new_image`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `return` to your function:

```
function image_fix_orientation(&$image, $filename) {
    $image = imagerotate($image, array_values([0, 0, 0, 180, 0, 0, -90, 0, 90])[@exif_read_data($filename)['Orientation'] ?: 0], 0);
     return $image;
}
```